# Number of producer threads in Kafka MirrorMaker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have started kafka MirrorMaker to mirror data across data center. There is an option `--num.streams` in MirrorMaker run config to decide the number of consumer threads. As far as I have read, `--num.producers` is deprecated from Kafka 0.9 and by default there is one producer thread to handle the consumption stream. Is this right? If the `--num.streams` is high, won't it create a bottleneck with just one producer thread?

If this is the expected behavior, is it better to start "N" MirrorMaker process with `--num.streams=1` so that there is 1:1 consumer and producer thread, instead of one MM process with `--num.streams="N"` to improve the MirrorMaker performance and prevent lag?